# How to get NSAppleScript PID in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, applescript

I have a command launched with `NSAppleScript`. How can I get PID of that command? I need it to close the process as soon as app is closed.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`runningApplications` API of NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications).  For example:

```
let runningApplications = NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications

for eachApplication in runningApplications {
    if let applicationName = eachApplication.localizedName {
        print("application is \(applicationName) & pid is \(eachApplication.processIdentifier)")
    }
}
```